# I have computer with no DVD-ROM Drive, is it possible to use Visual Studio 2010, if i download it from MSDN?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have a computer with no DVD-ROM Drive, is it possible to use Visual Studio 2010, if i download it from MSDN?

Comment: Yes. If your downloading an iso you may need some software to mount it.

Comment: go through this [Visual stuido ISO](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/vssetup/thread/ca6bb806-34b9-41c8-95dc-efb372556d93)..its for VS2005 but read the bottom comments `I used 7-zip to extract and install Visual Studio 2010 Express from an iso image. It was simple and easy. 7-zip extracted the files from iso image then run the setup.exe file from extracted files. 7-zip (open source Windows utility) can be used to extract other types of files, e.g., zip, tar, etc` it may help

Answer (score 1):

Yup.  If you downloaded an ISO, you can use [DAEMON Tools Lite](http://www.daemon-tools.cc/eng/products/dtLite) or other ISO mounting software to mount the ISO and install Visual Studio.  You can also use [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/download.html) to extract all the files out of the ISO and install from that.